# How can I measure real cpu usage in linux?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, kernel, profiling

I know that there are tools like **top** and **ps** for measuring CPU usage, but the way they measure the CPU usage is by measuring how much time the idle task was not running. So, for example, even if a CPU has a stall due to a cache miss, these tools would still consider the CPU to be occupied. However, what I want is for the profiling tool to consider the CPU as idle during a stall. Is there any tool which does that?

Comment: Check [this](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage).

Comment: OK, I see this tool lets you differentiate between time spent in user mode and kernel mode, but I think it still considers a CPU stalled on a cache miss or branch misprediction as occupied. Isn't it?

Comment: The CPU is busy/occupied when there's a cache miss or branch misprediction. It can't do anything else while resolving them, so it's by definition busy. What problem are you actually trying to solve? If you want to measure how much useful work the CPU does I guess you could use the perf framework to count the number of retired instructions and divide that by the theoretical maximum of instructions in the same amount of time or something like that. But it sounds like you're looking for some very specific information, so you'd better spell it out in the question.

Comment: @Art: I know about perf. But does perf work for multithreaded programs running on multicores? I mean do you for example need to check cache misses on each core or you can tell perf to give you the statistics for all the cores on which the multithreaded process is running?

Comment: @MetallicPriest perf has -a option that allows it to collect information from all hardware threads simultaneously: `perf record -a`. It requires root privileges.

Answer (score 7):

> tools like top and ps for measuring CPU usage, .. measure the CPU usage is by measuring how much time the idle task was not running.

No, they don't measure idle, they just read what kernel thinks about its CPU usage via /proc/stat (try `vmstat 1` tool too). Did you check that system-wide user + system times are accounted only by `idle`? I think, kernel just exports some stats of scheduler, which records user/system state on rescheduling, both on system timer and on blocking system calls (possibly one of callers of [`cpuacct_charge`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=3.16;i=cpuacct_charge), like `update_curr` - *Update the current task's runtime statistics.*).

/proc/stat example:

```
cat /proc/stat
cpu  2255 34 2290 22625563 6290 127 456
```

and decode by http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm

> The very first "cpu" line aggregates the numbers in all of the other "cpuN" lines. These numbers identify the amount of time the CPU has spent performing different kinds of work. Time units are in USER_HZ or **Jiffies** (typically hundredths of a second).
>
> The meanings of the columns are as follows, from left to right:

```
user: normal processes executing in user mode
nice: niced processes executing in user mode
system: processes executing in kernel mode
idle: twiddling thumbs
```

When we hear jiffie, it means that scheduler was used to get the numbers, not estimating of `idle` task (top even don't see this task or tasks with pid 0).

> So, for example, even if a CPU has a stall due to a cache miss, these tools would still consider the CPU to be occupied.

And basically (when there is no [SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading), like HT in Intels), CPU is occupied when your task has pipeline stall due to memory access (or taking wrong path with out-of-order). OS can't run other task, because task switch is more expensive that waiting this one stall.

Case of SMT is different, because there is hardware which either switchs two logical tasks on single hardware, or even (in fine grained SMT) mixing their instructions (microoperations) into the single stream to execute on  shared hardware. There are usually SMT statistic counters to check actual mixing.

> However, what I want is for the profiling tool to consider the CPU as idle during a stall. Is there any tool which does that?

Performance monitoring unit may have useful events for this. For example, `perf stat` reports some (on Sandy Bridge)

```
$ perf stat /bin/sleep 10

 Performance counter stats for '/bin/sleep 10':
      0,563759 task-clock                #    0,000 CPUs utilized          
             1 context-switches          #    0,002 M/sec                  
             0 CPU-migrations            #    0,000 M/sec                  
           175 page-faults               #    0,310 M/sec                  
       888 767 cycles                    #    1,577 GHz                    
       568 603 stalled-cycles-frontend   #   63,98% frontend cycles idle   
       445 567 stalled-cycles-backend    #   50,13% backend  cycles idle   
       593 103 instructions              #    0,67  insns per cycle        
                                         #    0,96  stalled cycles per insn
       115 709 branches                  #  205,246 M/sec                  
         7 699 branch-misses             #    6,65% of all branches        

  10,000933734 seconds time elapsed
```

So, it says that 0,5 jiffie (task-clock) was used by the sleep 10. It is too low to be accounted in classic rusage, and /usr/bin/time got 0 jiffie as task CPU usage (user + system):
$ /usr/bin/time sleep 10
0.00user 0.00system 0:10.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2608maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+210minor)pagefaults 0swaps

Then perf measures (counts with help of PMU) real cycles and real instructions executed by the task (and by kernel on behalf of the task) - `cycles` and `instructions` lines. Sleep has used 888k cycles but only 593k useful instructions were finished, and mean [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions_per_cycle) was 0.6-0.7 (30-40% stalls). Around 300k cycles was lost; and on Sandy bridge `perf` reports where they were lost - `stalled-cycles-*` events for frontend (decoder - CPU don't know what to execute due to branch miss or due to code not prefetched to L1I) and for backend (can't execute because instruction needs some data from memory which is not available at right time - memory stall).

Why we see more stalls inside CPU when there should be only 300k cycles without any instruction executed? This is because modern processors are often superscalar and out-of-order - they can start to executing several instructions every CPU clock tick, and even reorder them. If you want to see execution port utilization, try `ocperf` (perf wrapper) from Andi Kleen's [pmu-tools](https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools) and some Intel manuals about their PMU counters. There is also `toplev.py` script to "*identify the micro-architectural bottleneck for a workload*" without selecting Intel events by hands.